# code coverage tab not showing TFS 2015 build

Tags: tfs, build, code-coverage, tfs-2015

I am building some code using tfs 2015, running some karma tests and producing a Cobetura summary file with the karma-coverage reporter with karma.config as:

```
coverageReporter: {
        dir: 'testResults/stubs',
        includeAllSources: true,
        reporters: [
            { type: 'html', subdir: 'CoverageReporter' },
            { type: 'cobertura', subdir: 'cobetura', file: 'cobertura.xml' },
            { type: 'text', subdir: '.', file: 'testResults.txt' },
            { type: 'text-summary', subdir: '.', file: 'testSummary.txt' }
        ]
    }
```

I then publish the coverage results in the build definition as:

[image: Publish Step]

but in the build summary there is no code coverage tab to display the results:

[image: Build Summary]

the artifact is created with the data in though, so can be downloaded and viewed correctly.

[image: Coverage Artifact]

I have seen many posts showing the code coverage tab, but I cant seem to get it to show.  Please help.

output from build:

```
2018-11-21T12:02:06.8135130Z Executing the powershell script: C:\agent\tasks\PublishCodeCoverageResults\1.0.3\PublishCodeCoverageResults.ps1
2018-11-21T12:02:07.0166408Z ##[debug]Entering PublishCodeCoverage.ps1
2018-11-21T12:02:07.0322620Z ##[debug]codeCoverageTool = Cobertura
2018-11-21T12:02:07.0322620Z ##[debug]summaryFileLocation = C:\agent\_work\55\s\testResults\stubs\cobetura\cobertura.xml
2018-11-21T12:02:07.0322620Z ##[debug]reportDirectory = C:\agent\_work\55\s\testResults\stubs\CoverageReporter
2018-11-21T12:02:07.0322620Z ##[debug]additionalCodeCoverageFiles = 
2018-11-21T12:02:07.0478883Z Starting 'Publish-CodeCoverage' cmdlet...
2018-11-21T12:02:07.1416621Z Publishing coverage summary data to TFS server.
2018-11-21T12:02:07.2822777Z Publishing additional files to TFS server.
2018-11-21T12:02:07.4854044Z Max Concurrent Uploads 1, Max Creators 1
2018-11-21T12:02:07.5322833Z Found 38 files to upload.
2018-11-21T12:02:07.5322833Z Files found locally 38,
2018-11-21T12:02:07.5322833Z Files evaluated 0,
2018-11-21T12:02:07.5322833Z Files left to evaluate 38.,
2018-11-21T12:02:07.5322833Z Files created without upload 0,
2018-11-21T12:02:07.5479049Z Files uploaded 0
2018-11-21T12:02:07.5479049Z Files left to process 38
2018-11-21T12:02:07.5479049Z ---------------------------
2018-11-21T12:02:09.5949006Z Files found locally 38,
2018-11-21T12:02:09.5949006Z Files evaluated 38,
2018-11-21T12:02:09.5949006Z Files left to evaluate 0.,
2018-11-21T12:02:09.5949006Z Files created without upload 0,
2018-11-21T12:02:09.5949006Z Files uploaded 35
2018-11-21T12:02:09.5949006Z Files left to process 3
2018-11-21T12:02:09.5949006Z ---------------------------
2018-11-21T12:02:11.6109203Z Created 0 files without uploading content. Total files processed 38
2018-11-21T12:02:11.6418363Z Uploaded artifact 'C:\agent\_work\55\s\testResults\stubs\CoverageReporter' to container folder 'Code Coverage Report_13389' of build 13389.
2018-11-21T12:02:11.7824652Z Associated artifact 27182 with build 13389
```

Comment: What do the logs say for the steps where you're running your tests and uploading your results?

Comment: @DanielMann I have added this to the question now.